# popup out app in Teams from custom application

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

How can I create a popup window within the Microsoft Teams Desktop application that functions similarly to the "popup out app" button, instead of using window.open which opens a new browser window? The task module creates a modal popup, but we require non modal. The microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate opens a window, but it closes when navigating to other tabs within Teams.

Comment: Please Track this issue from here-https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/programmatically-popup-out-app-in-teams-from-custom-tab/m-p/3847561#M7896